# How to use bluebird promises only if browser doesn't support them natively

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, internet-explorer-11, axios, bluebird

I want to use `bluebird` promises to support browsers like IE11 when making http requests using `axios` but I'm not using any sort of build tool to bundle my client side dependencies. I'm just importing the `bluebird` library from a CDN in my html file. The problem with this is the bluebird promise immediately replaces the native promise on import. Is there any way I can do something similar to this on my client side JS:

```
if (Promise === undefined)
{
  // Use bluebird promise
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the various polyfills available? For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, or at least very close:

```
if (typeof Promise !== "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'path to your bluebird file.js'
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```